# How can I ffill previous values from second dataframe in pandas join

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to join 2 dataframes and fill down any nan values. However, df is missing the first value in df2. How can I fill that down from df?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
data = range(len(days)-1)
days = days.delete(3)
date_today = date_today + timedelta(days=3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'col_df': data})
df = df.set_index('test')
print(df)

days2 = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
data2 = range(len(days2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test': days2, 'col_df22': data2})
df2 = df2.set_index('test')
print(df2)

print(df2.join(df))
```

df

```
                            col_df
test                              
2020-12-08 15:22:00.997578       0
2020-12-09 15:22:00.997578       1
2020-12-10 15:22:00.997578       2
2020-12-12 15:22:00.997578       3
2020-12-13 15:22:00.997578       4
2020-12-14 15:22:00.997578       5
2020-12-15 15:22:00.997578       6
```

df2

```
                            col_df22
test                                
2020-12-11 15:22:00.997578         0
2020-12-12 15:22:00.997578         1
2020-12-13 15:22:00.997578         2
2020-12-14 15:22:00.997578         3
2020-12-15 15:22:00.997578         4
2020-12-16 15:22:00.997578         5
2020-12-17 15:22:00.997578         6
2020-12-18 15:22:00.997578         7
```

df2.join(df)

```
                           col_df22  col_df
test                                        
2020-12-11 15:22:00.997578         0     NaN
2020-12-12 15:22:00.997578         1     3.0
2020-12-13 15:22:00.997578         2     4.0
2020-12-14 15:22:00.997578         3     5.0
2020-12-15 15:22:00.997578         4     6.0
2020-12-16 15:22:00.997578         5     NaN
2020-12-17 15:22:00.997578         6     NaN
2020-12-18 15:22:00.997578         7     NaN
```

I want:

```
                            col_df22  col_df
test                                        
2020-12-11 15:22:00.997578         0     2.0
2020-12-12 15:22:00.997578         1     3.0
2020-12-13 15:22:00.997578         2     4.0
2020-12-14 15:22:00.997578         3     5.0
2020-12-15 15:22:00.997578         4     6.0
2020-12-16 15:22:00.997578         5     6.0
2020-12-17 15:22:00.997578         6     6.0
2020-12-18 15:22:00.997578         7     6.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df2, df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
                            col_df22  col_df
test                                        
2020-12-11 10:30:20.464611         0       2
2020-12-12 10:30:20.464611         1       3
2020-12-13 10:30:20.464611         2       4
2020-12-14 10:30:20.464611         3       5
2020-12-15 10:30:20.464611         4       6
2020-12-16 10:30:20.464611         5       6
2020-12-17 10:30:20.464611         6       6
2020-12-18 10:30:20.464611         7       6
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to join 2 dataframes and fill down any nan values

If you want to forward fill, you can used the `pandas.DataFrame.ffill()` method like this:

```
df2.join(df).ffill()

    test    col_df22    col_df
2020-12-11 15:38:50.658011  0   NaN
2020-12-12 15:38:50.658011  1   3.0
2020-12-13 15:38:50.658011  2   4.0
2020-12-14 15:38:50.658011  3   5.0
2020-12-15 15:38:50.658011  4   6.0
2020-12-16 15:38:50.658011  5   6.0
2020-12-17 15:38:50.658011  6   6.0
2020-12-18 15:38:50.658011  7   6.0
```

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.bfill()` to fill missing values backwards and you can combine the two eg:

```
df2.join(df).bfill().ffill()

test    col_df22    col_df
2020-12-11 15:38:50.658011  0   3.0
2020-12-12 15:38:50.658011  1   3.0
2020-12-13 15:38:50.658011  2   4.0
2020-12-14 15:38:50.658011  3   5.0
2020-12-15 15:38:50.658011  4   6.0
2020-12-16 15:38:50.658011  5   6.0
2020-12-17 15:38:50.658011  6   6.0
2020-12-18 15:38:50.658011  7   6.0
```

These fill NaN with the previous or next value for forward and backward filling respectively. Link to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html?highlight=ffill).